# How do I add the output of 8 randomly generated numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, integer, generated

```
elif a == "other":
    numberset = 0
    for count in range(8):
        nnn = randrange(33,126)
        print(nnn)
        numberset += nnn
```

I need to find out how to add all of the 8 generated numbers to make a total and then set that as a variable.

Comment: That's what you're doing right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not

```
numberset = sum(randrange(33, 126) for _ in range(8))
```

The argument of `sum` is a generator expression, i.e. it produces a generator that `sum` can iterate on, summing all the values given.

As you can see, I have used the `_` name as the counter. It is a naming convention for those variables that are not used further (i.e. in your loop, `count` is never used)

In case you want to print out the numbers as well (and keep them maybe) you can do

```
numbers = [randrange(33, 126) for _ in range(8)] # list comprehension
numberset = sum(numbers)
for n in numbers:
    print(n)
print('Sum is', numberset)
```

which produces

```
112
69
77
33
56
55
118
65
Sum is 585
```

Comment: preferred this answer as it sticks to standard libs (does not use `numpy`)

Comment: thank you for accepting my answer. Please see the added code for keeping/printing the random values.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(numpy.random.randint(min_randval,max_randval,8))
```

I guess